# Turning my inherited classes in an Abstract 'factory' C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, oop, factory

I'm not really pro and find my question quite hard to describe, so please ask if anything is unclear:

I have an abstract class called BaseDevice. 
Other devices, as Beacon and Transponder, inherit from BaseDevice.
For example the Beacon, it has the BaseClass methods PLUS its own **properties** and **methods**.
Let's say, the difference between these devices is that one has 2 LED's and one has a LCD

At the moment its not possible to make a device Transponder as well as Beacon (or i have to copypaste both into one new class, which is not wanted).

So, for example,
I want to be able to make a Device say to it: "You have one LED", "You have 2 LCDs" or whatever. and all the methods and properties that come with it should be available.
I still need to be able to see what device in my list of devices "Does he have one (or more) LED's"

Conclusion: I want to make turn my "Is A" into ""Has A" (as the Gang of Four recommend).

I have read once about the **Factory Design Pattern** which looked complicated. Would this be a good solution in this case?

Maybe I used some therms here that exceeds my knowledge, this project is the first one i used abstract classes etc. I'm really not that much of a Object Oriented Programmer. Design Patterns are quite hard for me to read, so answers that are easy to read are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me this sounds like you need a [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

> In object-oriented programming, the decorator pattern is a design pattern that allows new/additional behaviour to be added to an existing object dynamically.
>
> The decorator pattern is an alternative to subclassing. Subclassing adds behavior at compile time, and the change affects all instances of the original class; decorating can provide new behavior at runtime for individual objects.

The tricky part for you would be to define a common interface for all subclasses. If this is not possible, you can't use your objects polymorphically anyway.

Comment: Looks good!!  Thanks
Is the decorator able to only add methods or also properties?
And most important: can i see what a device is decorated with?

Comment: If you want to see new methods and properties, maybe a decorator is not the right choice for you. It is meant to enable handling of components polymorphically. Maybe you would be better off by simply aggregating the various components into the device as @Henk suggested. E.g. have a set of LCDs and another set of LEDs in the device, then push 2 LEDs into Device A and 1 LCD into Device B, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Henk deleted his answer i guess, but i get what he means. I'll see if something like that works out
I hoped for an prettier solution, cause the devices can have a lot more than just LEDs and LCDs.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is some additional classes for the components of your devices. For example, if there's some behavior related to LED's and you find yourself copy/pasting this code, it is a strong sign that you need an LED class.
This way you can have `List<LED>` field and `Add(LED newLed)` method which you can use on the concrete components. Essentially this is "Has A" relationship. You can have another class for LCD's, and now you can mix and match those things as you like in your concrete classes.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, this comes down to the same answer as Péter concluded (in the comments).